# JavaScript: Why can't I chain after my nested reduce function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How do I go up a level and return "id and title" pairs to my array? I get an error when
trying to use map after my reduce function.

```
Array.prototype.mergeAll = function(){
    return [].concat.apply([], this);
};

Array.prototype.flatMap = function(func){
    return this.map(function(item){
        return func(item);
    }).mergeAll();
};

function test() {
    var movieLists = [
        {
            name: "New Releases",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 150, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
                        { width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 654356453,
                    "title": "Bad Boys",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
                        { width: 140, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" }

                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id:432534, time:65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Thrillers",   
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 65432445,
                    "title": "The Chamber",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 130, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },
                        { width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 675465,
                    "title": "Fracture",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
                        { width: 120, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
                        { width: 300, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id:432534, time:65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


    // Use one or more flatMap, map, and reduce calls to create an array with the following items (order doesn't matter)
    // [
    //     {"id": 675465,"title": "Fracture","boxart":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
    //     {"id": 65432445,"title": "The Chamber","boxart":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },                
    //     {"id": 654356453,"title": "Bad Boys","boxart":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" },
    //     {"id": 70111470,"title": "Die Hard","boxart":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" }                
    // ];

    return movieLists.flatMap(function(movieList) {
            return movieList.videos.flatMap(function(vids){
                    return vids.boxarts.reduce(function(a,b){
                        if (a.width * a.height < b.width * b.height) return a;
                        else return b;                
                    });
            });
    });
}
test();
```

// this is what gets returned... I want to add higher level object properties also. Specifically ID and Title.

```
=> [ { width: 150,
    height: 200,
    url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg' },
  { width: 140,
    height: 200,
    url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg' },
  { width: 130,
    height: 200,
    url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg' },
  { width: 120,
    height: 200,
    url: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg' } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that I think will work:

```
return movieLists.flatMap(function (movieList) {
    return movieList.videos.flatMap(function (vids) {
        return { 
            id: vids.id,
            title: vids.title,
            boxart: vids.boxarts.reduce(function (a, b) {
                if (a.width * a.height < b.width * b.height) return a;
                else return b;
            }).url
        }
    });
});
```

You have access to the video info in that inner flatmap call, so this is where you need to construct your custom returned object that has the id and title.  It might be clearer to rename the `vids` parameter to `video` or something. I Hope this helps! Let me know if you need any clarification.